# Is it possible to import OneNote to Zim

Tags: ubuntu, import, ms-office, onenote

I would like to import existing Microsoft OneNote notebooks to [Zim](http://www.zim-wiki.org/) on Ubuntu. Is this possible?

I tried opening the OneNote file, but the format is not supported. Is there a workaround? A plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible - you could build a tool that used the OneNote API to import notes into Zim. Such tool does not exist currently.

http://dev.onenote.com/